# Scroll tkinter ttk Entry text to the End in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI form using Python tkinter. For a ttk Entry widget, I want to set a default text. I do that using the insert() as shown below-

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
e = ttk.Entry(root, width=20)
e.pack()
e.insert(0, 'text greater than width of the widget')
```

The widget shows the beginning portion of the inserted text. Is there a way that I can make it scroll to the end of the inserted text by default?

Answer (score 7):

You can call the `xview` method to scroll a given index into view:

```
e.xview("end")
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. This seems to work correctly for pack geometry but not for grid geometry. Do you know the solution for grid geometty?

Comment: @AdityaKumar: not true. `pack` and `grid` have absolutely no bearing on the `xview` method whatsoever. The two (xview, and grid/pack) are completely unrelated. This absolutely will scroll the entry widget to the end with either.